# Ansible inventory plugin for azure throws encoding error

Tags: azure, ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

From what I understand using ansible-inventory-plugins over dynamic-inventory-provisioners is the new way of handling dynamic hosts, as of cloud providers and so on.

So, at first I've set the azure credentials in my environment:

```
 ± env | grep AZ
AZURE_SECRET=asdf
AZURE_TENANT=asdf
AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=asdf
AZURE_CLIENT_ID=asdf
```

Next, I've written an ansible.cfg with the following content:

```
± cat ansible.cfg
[inventory]
enable_plugins = azure_rm
```

Finally I wrote the yaml file with the minimum setting as shown at the [ansible inventory plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.html) page:

```
± cat foo.azure_rm.yaml 
---
plugin: azure_rm
```

When I am running the ansible-inventory binary on that file, I get:

```
± ansible-inventory -i foo.azure_rm.yaml --list
 [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /path/to/foo.azure_rm.yaml with azure_rm plugin: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /path/to/foo.azure_rm.yaml as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "ungrouped": {}
}
```

Summing up: The main problem seems to be the line:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /path/to/foo.azure_rm.yaml with azure_rm plugin: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Help, anyone?

Comment: Check encoding of the /path/to/foo.azure_rm.yaml file. Make sure it is something "normal" like UTF-8

Comment: @M_dk, yes it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it in a github fork and use pipenv to include this version in my environment. Actually it should be a backup port from devel, where the problem is already fixed. Maybe I'll fix this during the coming days and do a PR at ansible to include it into stable-2.7, but maybe the better option is to wait for 2.8 in May.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an error in the script. Adding the debug flag to Ansible gives me the following stacktrace:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 273, in parse_source
  plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 235, in parse
  self._get_hosts()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 292, in _get_hosts
  self._process_queue_batch()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 412, in _process_queue_batch
  result.handler(r['content'], **result.handler_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 357, in _on_vm_page_response
  self._hosts.append(AzureHost(h, self, vmss=vmss))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 466, in __init__
  self.default_inventory_hostname = '{0}_{1}'.format(vm_model['name'], hashlib.sha1(vm_model['id']).hexdigest()[0:4])
```

It seems this was only recently fixed: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/46608. So either you'll have to wait for 2.8 or use development version.

Comment: Actually, I've gone backwards by using python 2.7 in my pipenv which renders dynamic inventory plugin to be working for now. The drawback is, that molecule now is not working correctly. A dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue and solve it by using python3

you can check your ansible python version with the following command

```
  ansible --version | grep "python version"
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) [GCC 7.4.0]
```

install all python3 packages

```
  pip3 install ansible azure azure-cli
```

if needed export env variable for the authentication

```
  export ANSIBLE_AZURE_AUTH_SOURCE=cli
```

then run ansible inventory with

```
python3 $(which ansible-inventory) -i my.azure_rm.yaml --graph
```

my.azure_rm.yml file looks like this one:

```
plugin: azure_rm
include_vm_resource_groups:
  - my_resource_group_rg
auth_source: cli
```